# If $g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ and has the maximum value $M$ then find the number of ways in which $M$ can be resolved as a product of $2$ divisors.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function defined in $[-3,3]$ such that $f(0)=-4, f'(3)=0, f'(-3)=12$ and $f''(x)\ge-2\;\forall x\in[-3,3]$. If $g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ and has the maximum value $M$ then find the number of ways in which $M$ can be resolved as a product of $2$ divisors.

$$f''(x)+2\ge0\\\implies(f'(x)+2x)'\ge0\\\implies f'(x)+2x\;\text{is non-decreasing}\\\implies f'(x)\;\text{is non-decreasing}$$

But as per given data, $f'(x)$ has decreased. So, what's wrong in my approach?

**EDIT:** From the comments, I got that $f(x)=-x^2+6x-4\implies g(x)=-\dfrac{x^3}3+3x^2-4x$

To find maximum value, $g'(x)=0\implies x=3+\sqrt5$

$g(3+\sqrt5)=6+\dfrac{10\sqrt5}3$

Looks like I have made a mistake. Can you point out? Thanks.

Comment: $f'(x) +2x$ is non-deceasing does not implies that $f'(x)$ is non-decreasing. Say for example $f'(x) = -x$.

Comment: @ArcticChar thanks

Comment: That is a very good idea. You can get $f'(3) + 2.3 = 6 $ and $f'(3) + 2(-3) = 6$ both equal to $6$. What can you say about $f'(x) + 2x$ then?

Comment: @Azlif it implies that $f'(x)+2x$ is constant.

Comment: Great! Now you can get $f(x)$ and solve the problem.

Comment: Therefore, $f'(x)+2x=6$

Comment: Therefore, $f(x)+x^2=6x-4$

Comment: Therefore, $g(x)=-\frac{x^3}3+3x^2-4x$

Comment: @Azlif Hi. I have made an edit. Can you check? Thanks.

Comment: @aarbee The domain is $[-3,3]$ but your value is not inside the interval. So the maximum would be at the end point of the interval.

Comment: @Azlif Thankyou so much.